# Why can't I pipe npm install to sed, while preserving color and progress updates?

Tags: node.js, bash, sed, npm, npm-install

If I type `npm i | sed "s/^/    /"`, the output of `npm i` is not spaced over when printed to stdout. E.g. I get the following:

```
$ npm i | sed "s/^/    /"
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 
(node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN [name_removed]@0.0.2 No repository field.
npm WARN [name_removed]@0.0.2 No license field.
```

instead of:

```
$ npm i | sed "s/^/    /"
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 
    (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
    fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
    {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN [name_removed]@0.0.2 No repository field.
    npm WARN [name_removed]@0.0.2 No license field.
```

Edit:
The warnings are going to stderr (duh...), so i need to use `npm i 2>&1 | sed 's/^/    /`, but this removes colors from the output and I don't see the progress bar, which you can see in the gif below.

[image]
[image]

Edit2: Color is fixed via `npm i --color=always | sed 's/^/    /`, but i still don't see the progress bar. In addition, it seems to add lines to the line following all the output...I assume this is caused by a color code being output? You can see this phenomenon in the gif below:

[image]

Current status:
[image]

Comment: You sure what you are seeing is from STDOUT and not STDERR?

Comment: To determine the answer to AIG's question, try `npm i 2>&1 | sed ...`

Comment: @AlG part of it is definitely going to STDERR.

Comment: @WilliamPursell if I do that, I no longer see the progress text shown during the `npm i` call, but the 4 warnings are correctly spaced. However, I lose the colored text from `npm i` when it passes through sed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're experiencing several issues here, most of them related to the way `npm` handles its output.

#### Catching warnings

Note first that `npm` outputs *warnings* and updates *progress* on `stderr`, while only final results go to `stdout`. So, in order to process warning, you'll have to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` with something like:

```
npm install 2>&1 | sed 's/^/    /'
```

#### Preserving color

But now with `stderr` piped to `sed` process, you'll notice `npm` omits coloring! This, however, is a standard behaviour for most command line tools (like `ls`, `grep`, etc.). They'll output ANSI escape (color) sequences only when the output is going to a `TTY` device (i.e. to user, not file, or pipe). The usual way of determining if a file descriptor is connected to a `TTY` is via [`isatty(int fd)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) function. It turns out ([after](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/latest/lib/npm.js#L293) [some](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_tty) [digging](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/63243bcb330408d511b3945c53719425d8b7abb8/deps/uv/src/unix/tty.c#L265)) `npm` is using the same mechanism.

To fix coloring problem, we have two options:

**(1)** We can *force* color output with [`--color=always`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#color) option (similar to `ls`, `grep`, and others):

```
npm install --color=always 2>&1 | sed 's/^/    /'
```

or, **(2)** we can use a tool called [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) which will *fake* a `TTY` output device for any program/script run:

```
script -feqc 'npm install' /dev/null | sed 's/^/    /'
```

Note we don't have to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` anymore, `script` does that for us. Also, `script` will save the complete output to a file of our choosing (in this case we don't need it, so we're saying `/dev/null`). (Btw, `-f` will flush output after each write, `-e` will ensure the exit code of the command is returned to parent/shell, `-q` forces *quiet* mode with no info messages, and with `-c cmd` we provide the command to run.)

#### Preserving progress updates

Ok, so now we have warnings indented and color preserved, but we've lost our progress (bar) updates!

Why has this happened? Well, because `npm` outputs the complete progress in a single line. On each progress update it will move to character position zero (of the same line!) and print the new progress. For `sed`, **the complete progress is just a single line**, and since `sed` is line-oriented, it waits until the end of the line (`\n`) before any processing (and output).

Obviously, we need to go one level lower - and process character by character. To achieve the effect of indentation, we'll replace each occurrence of `\n` with `\n<4 spaces>`.

Usually, for character translation we can use `tr`, but here we need more than that, since in some cases (`\n`) we need to expand one character to several. One way to do it is with this simple `bash` script/function:

```
#!/bin/bash
# read each character of stdin, indenting each line
interactive_indent() {
    local space='    '
    echo -n "$space"
    while IFS= read -r -d '' -n1 chr; do
        [[ $chr == $'\n' ]] && chr="\\n\\r$space"
        [[ $chr == $'\r' ]] && chr="\\r$space"
        echo -ne "$chr"
    done
    echo -ne '\r'
}
```

For example:

```
$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\rthree' | interactive_indent
    one
    three
```

**Finally, we come to the solution** for our interactive `npm` process:

```
script -feqc 'npm install' /dev/null | interactive_indent
```

This will pass-through each character (displaying progress), while indenting each line (after `\n` or `\r`).

Note that our `interactive_indent` function is a little more complex than a simple `\n`-to-`\n<spaces>` replacer. We also had to handle carriage returns (`\r`) which are heavily used by `npm` for both progress update and dependency tree drawing, and ensure each new line starts at position zero (hence the `\r` alongside each `\n`).

Comment: color worked beautifully; do you know how to fix the missing progress bar that's shown in the two gifs?

Comment: why do you prefer script over `--color=always`

Comment: I don't, but if you want progress output, you need to "fool" `npm` into thinking it's writing to TTY, hence you need something like `script`.

Comment: Ah I see...I assume if I wanted to replicate the exact progress output of npm (where it replaces the previous progress line with the updated progress line) I'd have to do extra parsing of the output and do the same text replace operation, just with spaces inserted? Your answer works, but I get the updated progress line on a new line, so the previous progress is not replaced.

Comment: Actually if I'm understanding the output correctly, a new progress line is used for every new "task/item" being worked on...so for the same npm i "task" it will put its progress on one line and replace it as expected, but the progress is moved to a new line for every new "task"

Comment: Hmm, for me it works as it's supposed to, at least I think. Can you post another gif showing what's the problem?

Comment: i added a current status gif

Comment: So, it looks like it almost works? But, I'm afraid I can't debug it, since I can't reproduce it. (Btw, which OS/platform you run it on? Maybe the problem is with `\r`/`\n` behaviour in your terminal?) If you can create a minimal example (`package.json`) we can run and verify the problem, it would be best to ask a new question.

Comment: i'm on ubuntu 16.04 using gnome terminal